# Proper syntax for out-of-line member functions, taking a non-type-template-parameter of a member type defined in terms of another class' member type?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, visual-c++, clang

For any templated class `C<T>`, which contains member type `C<T>::mem_type`, which is defined in terms of a member type of another class (such as `U<T>::mem_type`), what is the proper syntax for taking a non-type-template parameter of `C<T>::mem_type` in an out-of-line member function definition?

```
template<typename T>
struct U { using mem_type = T; };

template<typename T>
class C {
  public:
    using mem_type = typename U<T>::mem_type;

    template<mem_type N>
    void func();
};
template<typename T>
template<typename C<T>::mem_type N> // Surprisingly, not this simple.
void C<T>::func() {}
```

Clang, GCC, and MSVC disagree on how this should be handled, and I'm not sure which is correct.

---

Consider the following:

```
#include <cstdlib>

template<typename CharT>
class One {
  public:
    using size_type  = size_t;
    using value_type = CharT;
};

template<typename CharT>
class Two {
  public:
    using one_type   = One<CharT>;
    using size_type  = typename one_type::size_type;
    using value_type = typename one_type::value_type;

    template<size_type N>                                                    // Ctor-A1.
    //template<typename Two::size_type N>                                    // Ctor-A2.
    Two(const value_type (&str)[N]);

    template<size_type N> void f1(const value_type (&str)[N]);               // F1-A.
    template<typename Two::size_type N> void f2(const value_type (&str)[N]); // F2-A.
};

template<typename CharT>
//template<typename Two<CharT>::size_type N>                                 // Ctor-B1.
template<typename One<CharT>::size_type N>                                   // Ctor-B2.
Two<CharT>::Two(const value_type (&str)[N]) {}

template<typename CharT>
//template<typename Two<CharT>::size_type N>                                 // F1-B1.
template<typename One<CharT>::size_type N>                                   // F1-B2.
void Two<CharT>::f1(const value_type (&str)[N]) {}

template<typename CharT>
//template<typename Two<CharT>::size_type N>                                 // F2-B1.
template<typename One<CharT>::size_type N>                                   // F2-B2.
void Two<CharT>::f2(const value_type (&str)[N]) {}
```

Given this code, by selectively commenting and uncommenting the labeled lines, the following compiler behaviour can be observed:

- For `Ctor-A1` or `F1-A`:

  - Both Clang and MSVC will match it to `Ctor-B2` or `F1-B2`, respecitively, but emit an error when attempting to match it to `Ctor-B1` or `F1-B1`.
  - GCC will match it to either `Ctor-B1` or `Ctor-B2`, or either `F1-B1` or `F1-B2`, respectively.
- For `Ctor-A2` or `F2-A`:

  - Clang will match it to `Ctor-B2` or `F2-B2`, respectively, but emit an error when attempting to match it to `Ctor-B1` or `F2-B1`.
  - GCC will match it to either `Ctor-B1` or `Ctor-B2`, or either `F2-B1` or `F2-B2`, respectively.
  - MSVC will match it to `Ctor-B1` or `F2-B1`, respectively, but emit an error when attempting to match it to `Ctor-B2` or `F2-B2`.

For comparison, if `Two` isn't a templated type, and defines member `one_type` as `One<char>`, all three compilers will consider `template<typename Two::size_type N>` and `template<typename One<char>::size_type N>` to be equivalent.

---

Given this information, the following conclusions can be made:

When a member type of one class is used to define a member type of a second class, and a member function of that second class takes a non-type-template-parameter of that types...

- Clang: Matches it to the member type of the first class, even when explicitly specified as the member type of the second class.  It appears that Clang matches the definition, not the name.
- GCC: Matches either.  In this case, since `Two<CharT>::size_type` is defined as `One<CharT>::size_type`, GCC sees both as the same type.  It will not match either to `size_t`, however.
- MSVC: Matches it to the member type of the first class, unless explicitly specified as the member type of the second class; if explicitly specified, then it matches the member type of second class.  It appears that MSVC tries to match the name, but falls back to matching the definition if it gets confused.

Of these two, Clang and MSVC in particular have contradictory behaviours when the parameter type is explicitly specified as `Two<CharT>::size_type`, with MSVC appearing to be correct.  Meanwhile, GCC matches either, which appears to be correct when the parameter type *isn't* explicitly specified.

**Considering this inconsistency, I don't want my code to be tied to any specific compiler, especially when it could potentially break when erroneous behaviour is fixed.  What is the correct syntax, according to the standard?**

Comment: Note: If it matters, this came up when designing a string literal template class that couples to `std::basic_string`, allowing finer control over the string generated if it's converted to a `basic_string` during runtime.